# Centering camera on player div

Tags: javascript, html5, roguelikes

I've been making a **roguelike-style game** in HTML5 **without using canvas (only divs)** with **pure JS** (**[fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/t38k1j8w/)**). I've been trying to **enlarge the tile size (font size) while keeping the player centered within the camera.** For some reason, when the tile size isn't equal to the map size, the camera will be slightly off.

**Note that the 3D effect is on purpose. Without it, the camera is still off center, and I believe it adds some much needed depth to the scene. :D**

When `tileScale` (line 4 in the fiddle) is `9` (very undesirable; the dots on the player's y axis should be aligned, not at a slight angle):

[image: The camera is off!]

When `tileScale` is `25` (on point!):

[image: The camera is on point.]

Here's some relevant (trimmed) code:

```
window.onresize = function(){
    game.viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    game.viewportHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    game.windowSize = Math.min(game.viewportWidth, game.viewportHeight);
    // Droid Sans Mono has a ratio of 3:4 (width:height), conveniently.
    // This may be problematic. I'm not sure.
    game.tileWidth = game.windowSize*.6 / game.tileScale;
    game.tileHeight = game.windowSize*.8 / game.tileScale;
}

// Update the camera position (needs help?)
this.updateCamera = function(){
    // Get player coordinates (-.5 because we need to get the player tile center)
    // times the tileWidth plus the game window (inner square) size divided by two.
    var left = ((-game.player.x-.5)*game.tileWidth+game.windowSize/2)+"px";
    var top = ((-game.player.y-.5)*game.tileHeight+game.windowSize/2)+"px";
    game.planeContainer.style.left = left;
    game.planeContainer.style.top = top;
}
```

**How can I ensure that the dots in the center of the screen will be always lined up, instead of on a slight angle?** My current evidence suggests that the position of the `game.planeContainer` object isn't being established correctly.

I know this is a super-tough problem, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

*([Another fiddle link, in case you skimmed over the first one. :D](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/t38k1j8w/))*

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking at in those screenshots. What about those images is a problem?

Comment: I guess the problem wasn't exactly clear, I've edited my post. Basically, the dots on the player's y-axis should be aligned, as seen in the second screenshot.

Comment: oh so you *don't* want that perspective look. I'm not familiar with that particular API, but it looks like game.planeContainer is a 3D plane being viewed at a slight angle.

Comment: @jhocking, looking at the CSS, that is exactly what's happening. OP: The container div has `perspective: 750px` and the plane div has `transform: rotateX(45deg)`

Comment: I've edited the post; the 3D effect is there on purpose and my goal is to keep it while properly centering the container div (e.g., The second picture has a slight 3D effect while being centered). :)

Comment: @GrandonBroseph your issue appears to be coming from using mixed units in the CSS and JS. You might as well just use `px` everywhere as you are already handling window resize. As such, I'll go ahead and remove my answer.

Comment: @XGundam05 If I'm reading this correctly, you're suggesting that I remove the `vw`, `vh` and `%` values in the CSS, and instead handle those values entirely through JS, right? I'm not sure if that would work, since I'm starting to think that the culprit is somewhere in the calculation of `tileWidth` and `tileHeight` in the `window.onresize` function.

Comment: @GrandonBroseph that's what I'm saying. If you size everything via JS, there will be less issue in dealing with the calculations, and it will be far easier to debug the issue.

Comment: @XGundam05 Wow, looks like that did it somehow! CSS always messes things up lol. [Here's an updated fiddle with a dungeon generator.](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/t38k1j8w/80/) Perhaps you could consider putting this in answer format so I can accept it? That would be awesome. Thanks so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution.
Simply remove the position: absolute; CSS rule on inner-text. This works on all (tileScale)'s that I thought reasonable to test.

Here's the code without that rule http://jsfiddle.net/t38k1j8w/76/

I also found some other styling things and could explain my process but wasn't sure if it was important.

Comment: At first glance, this seems to work, but setting `tileScale` to `4` and looking at the line below the player shows that this does not exactly center the div (take a look at the leftmost yellow dot on said line). I'll keep this in mind; but note that the `position: absolute` rule here exists to center the text character in its containing tile div. Thanks for the insight, though!

Comment: There was another way to do it but I stopped half of the way though since I found that removal to work. Can you explain the alignment you want in a little more detail.